# Measure model accuracy on Prophet

Tags: python, forecast, facebook-prophet

I'm running this code. Forecasting for multiple time series with Prophet but don't know how to evaluate the model.

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\XXX.csv')
ids = data['id'].unique()
series = []
for id in ids:
   f = data[data['id'] == id]
   series.append(f)

def run_prophet(timeserie):
    model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=False,daily_seasonality=False)
    model.fit(timeserie)
    forecast = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=90, include_history=False)
    forecast = model.predict(forecast)
    return forecast

results = list(map(lambda timeserie: run_prophet(timeserie), series))

results[0] 
results[1]
```

The structure of the data is something like this:

```
id       ds         y
id1   2017-01-01    12
id2   2017-01-01    15
id3   2017-01-01    16
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by importing this:
`from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, mean_absolute_error`
then
`r2_score(original price,predicted price)`
this is same for the rest,
note:both arrays should have equal length of samples.